# Manipute image with php

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to create a picture and fill its pixels randomly.
But I have the following problems:
1) I did not find much information on using the gd library
2) I do not know how many bytes are each pixele of imagene generated using me 'imagecreatetruecolor ()'

I leave a picture of how my program works, I seek to do this with all the bitmap (picture) ...

image here: [a link](http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2014/04/28/140428061616205148.png)

```
<?php
function num_random(){
$desde = 0; 
$hasta = 255;
$num = rand ($desde , $hasta);
return $num;
}



header("Content-Type: image/png");
$width = 250; //ancho
$height = 250; //alto
$im = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

for ($i=0; $i < $height ; $i++) {  //recorro vertical
    for ($j=0; $j < $width ; $j++) {  //recorro lineal
        $color = imagecolorallocate($im, num_random(),num_random(),num_random());
        imagesetpixel ($im ,$i,$j ,$color);
    }

 }

 imagepng($im);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php printf("<img src='%s'> ", $im);?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks for yours anwers :)

Comment: what do you want?.. i dont see a problem here

Comment: i want put color to all pixels in the bitmap(image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace imagecreate by imagecreatetruecolor

```
$im = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
```

by

```
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: y no puedes poner que la respuesta te sirve?